# PHP built-in function to assign each element of an array to a variable, does it exist?

Tags: php, arrays

For example:

```
$array = array('f', 'b');
assign($foo, $bar, $array);

// now $foo = 'f' and $bar = 'b'
```

Does something like this exist in the PHP language? I have never needed something like this before and cannot find anything that will do this.

I just wanted to make sure before I write the function myself - I don't want to write something that already exists within the language.

Comment: A similar setting exists for requested variables `register_globals` but regardless of that I would strongly advise you not to do that. It makes it superbly harder to debug, and open all sorts of doors for hacking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list ($foo, $bar) = $array;
```

`list()` is something like the opposite of `array()` and its a language construct. Its especially important to know, that even if its listed in the functions reference of the manual ([`list()`](http://php.net/list)), it isn't, because *no* function is writeable.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)! I had forgotten about `list`. Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Looking at the other answers it seems, that you are not alone. I'm a little bit surprised...

Comment: @KingCrunch, yeah, I've even used `list`, but my PHP is obviously getting a bit rusty.

Comment: I misread the question thinking it needed to happen to all variables within any dynamic array.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close to PHP's **[extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)** function.

You need to specify the var name as they key for each value in the array though.

```
$array = array('foo' => 'f', 'bar' => 'b');
extract($array);
// now $foo = 'f' and $bar = 'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use php's `list()` function

```
$array = array('f', 'b');
list($foo, $bar) = $array;
```

now it is

```
$foo = 'f' and $bar = 'b';
```

[php.net/list](https://www.php.net/list)

Comment: It was probably because you tried to snipe the accepted answer by posting a very simple solution first, and then editing in more detail, even after your solution was already posted as an answer. Just a guess, it wasn't me!

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar, if there was a down-vote, it's been removed.